# How do I rewrite Terraform (HCL) without regex?

Tags: terraform

I have terraform that looks like:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    region = "ap-southeast-1"
    key    = "01-service-quota-state.json"
    bucket = "foobar-dev-infra-tf-state"
    dynamodb_table = "foobar-dev-infra-tf-state-lock"
  }

  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}
```

Since we use a Makefile to initialise the backend, I have a large terraform repository where I want to reduce and refactor the above to:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {}
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}
```

Initially I was planning to do this with sed, though I was hinted that I could do some sort of .tf -> JSON -> jq -> .tf transformation. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can write a small node script using [hcl2-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hcl2-parser) with the parseToString method to transform hcl to json

Answer (score 0):

Wrong answer, though to solve this problem I ended up using VS code search and replace regex `backend "s3" \{([\n\s\S]*?)\}`

https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/discussions/2334#discussioncomment-3923925